# what js code that will get the value from the div class name from the append. () to get the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a like a data calculator that will compute the inputted number.

My problem is that when adding new input, it cannot get or add the value to the total.

this are the sample out.

When you click the plus(+) button and add new number value, it will not add up to the total.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  const $expenses_debit = $(".expenses_debit");
  const $res_debit = $("#sub_debit");
  $expenses_debit.on("input", () => {

    const total = $expenses_debit.get().reduce((acc, el) => (acc += parseFloat(el.value, 10) || 0), 0).toFixed(2);
    $res_debit.val(total);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap27"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button27"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<tr><td><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#" class="remove_field27"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-light">-</button></a></div><div class="col-lg-9"><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><input type="text" name="" style="font-size:12px" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Check No" id="expendable_furniture_check[]"></div></div></div></td><th>Furniture and Fixtures</th><td>12345</td><td><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span><input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm expenses_debit operating_debit total1" placeholder="0.00" id="expendable_furniture_debit[]"></div></td><td><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span><input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm " placeholder="0.00" disabled></div></td></tr>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field27", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <table class="table table-sm table-hover table-fixed" align="center" style="font-size: 9pt">
    <thead style="font-size: 11pt">
      <tr align="center">
        <th width="15%">Check Series</th>
        <th width="20%">Accounts and Explanations</th>
        <th>UACS Object Code</th>
        <th width="20%">Debit Amount</th>
        <th width="20%">Credit Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="input_fields_wrap27">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light add_field_button27">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
              <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <input type="text" name="" style="font-size:12px" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Check No" id="expendable_furniture_check[]">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <th>Furniture and Fixtures</th>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span>
            <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" class="form-control form-control-sm expenses_debit operating_debit total1" placeholder="0.00" id="expendable_furniture_debit[]">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span>
            <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
          </div>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <h5 align="right"><b>SUB TOTAL</b></h5>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 16pt">P</span>
            <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" name="sub_debit" class="form-control form-control-sm operating_expenses" style="font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold;"
              placeholder="0.00" disabled="" id="sub_debit">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 16pt">P</span>
            <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" name="sub_credit" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="sub_credit" style="font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold;"
              placeholder="0.00" disabled="">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: by total you mean the sum of the `input`s inside the "Debit Amount" column ?

Comment: Learning about [event delegates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) and [templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) would help you write this code in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that at the time you add the event handler to the input field (`$expenses_debit.on("input", () => {`) there is only one input field. If you add another one the event handler will not be added automatically, you have to do it yourself. You could do so by wrapping the first lines in a function and call it at the beginning and when you add a new input field.

```js
function init_input()
{
  const $expenses_debit = $(".expenses_debit");
  const $res_debit = $("#sub_debit");
  $expenses_debit.on("input", () => {

   const total = $expenses_debit.get().reduce((acc, el) => (acc += parseFloat(el.value, 10) || 0), 0).toFixed(2) ;
    $res_debit.val(total);
  });
}

jQuery($ => {
  
  init_input();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper       = $(".input_fields_wrap27"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".add_field_button27"); //Add button ID
  
  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<tr><td><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#" class="remove_field27"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-light">-</button></a></div><div class="col-lg-9"><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><input type="text" name="" style="font-size:12px" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Check No" id="expendable_furniture_check[]"></div></div></div></td><th>Furniture and Fixtures</th><td>12345</td><td><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span><input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm expenses_debit operating_debit total1" placeholder="0.00" id="expendable_furniture_debit[]"></div></td><td><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span><input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm " placeholder="0.00" disabled></div></td></tr>'); 

      // add event handler to the new input field
      init_input();

    }
  });
  
  $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field27", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).closest("tr").remove(); x--;
  })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
 <table class="table table-sm table-hover table-fixed" align="center" style="font-size: 9pt">
                    <thead style="font-size: 11pt">
                        <tr align="center">
                            <th width="15%">Check Series</th>   
                            <th width="20%">Accounts and Explanations</th>
                            <th>UACS Object Code</th>
                            <th width="20%">Debit Amount</th>
                            <th width="20%">Credit Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
<tbody class="input_fields_wrap27">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light add_field_button27">+</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-9">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                        <input type="text" name="" style="font-size:12px" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Check No" id="expendable_furniture_check[]">
                                    </div>                              
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>                                       
                        <th>Furniture and Fixtures</th>
                        <td>12345</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                              <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span>
                              <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" class="form-control form-control-sm expenses_debit operating_debit total1" placeholder="0.00" id="expendable_furniture_debit[]">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                              <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span>
                              <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
                            </div>                  
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>  
                        <td colspan="2"><h5 align="right"><b>SUB TOTAL</b></h5></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                              <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 16pt">P</span>
                              <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" name="sub_debit" class="form-control form-control-sm operating_expenses" style="font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold;" placeholder="0.00" disabled="" id="sub_debit" >
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                              <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 16pt">P</span>
                              <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" name="sub_credit" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="sub_credit"  style="font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold;"  placeholder="0.00" disabled="">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>           
           </table>
</body>
```